# How do I create a route to /admin for /app/controllers/admin_controller.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to have many actions for an AdminController in `app/controllers/admin_controller.rb`. I tried

```
  namespace :admin do
    get '/', to: 'admin#index'
  end
```

However it is looking in an `admin/` subfolder.

```
>rake routes | grep -i admin
                     admin GET    /admin(.:format)                            admin/admin#index
```

I tried

```
resource :admin, only: [:index]
```

However, no routes were generated.

```
>rake routes | grep admin
```

I don't need `admin#create`, `admin#show`, etc. These are going to be very specific methods like `#approve`, and whatnot.

I tried

```
  controller :admin do
    get 'admin/', action: :index
    get :approve
  end
```

And it worked for `admin/`, but not `admin/approve`.

```
>rake routes | grep admin
                     admin GET    /admin(.:format)                            admin#index
                   approve GET    /approve(.:format)                          admin#approve
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found it. Looks messier than I thought though.

```
  scope :admin, as: :admin, controller: :admin do
    get '/', action: :index
    get :approve
  end
```

---

```
>rake routes | grep admin
                     admin GET    /admin(.:format)                            admin#index
             admin_approve GET    /admin/approve(.:format)                    admin#approve
```